# Unable to Install Mariadb 10.2.2 or later on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(32Bit) fom mariadb sources

Tags: 18.04, server, mariadb

I've migrated from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit to 18.04 LTS.

Since 18.04 installs Mariadb 10.1.48, have added following Mariadb 10.2 repository to /etc/apt/sources.list , after updating the following is shown as candidate,

```
# apt-cache policy mariadb-server
mariadb-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:10.2.39+maria~bionic
  Version table:
     1:10.2.39+maria~bionic 500
        500 http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.2/repo/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     1:10.2.38+maria~bionic 500
        500 http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.2/repo/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     1:10.2.37+maria~bionic 500
        500 http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.2/repo/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     1:10.1.48-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     1:10.1.29-6 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

And when trying to install mariadb-client and mariadb-server, i get the following error.

```
# apt install -f mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.2 (>= 1:10.2.39+maria~bionic) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I installed mariadb 10.2.2 xenial version and tried to upgrade in vain. And even tried to find old i386 deb packages.

When installed xenial source, i was able to install mariadb-10.2, but it would not run.

Any help to run Mariadb 10.2.2 or later on 32bit bionic is appreciated.

Thanks,

Update - 1

```
# apt install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.2 (>= 1:10.2.39+maria~bionic) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@NMS-NTP-Server:~# apt install mariadb-server-10.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mariadb-server-10.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mariadb-server-10.2' has no installation candidate


# apt list --installed | grep maria

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libmariadbclient18/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,bionic-updates,now 1:10.1.48-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
mariadb-client-10.2/now 10.2.2+maria-1~xenial i386 [installed,local]
mariadb-client-core-10.2/now 10.2.2+maria-1~xenial i386 [installed,local]
mariadb-common/unknown,now 1:10.2.39+maria~bionic all [installed,automatic]
mariadb-server-core-10.2/now 10.2.2+maria-1~xenial i386 [installed,local]
mysql-common/unknown,now 1:10.2.39+maria~bionic all [installed]
```

Update - 2

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [294 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]     
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [295 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [9,272 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]     
Hit:9 https://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.2/repo/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [51.4 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [51.4 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [57.9 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata [294 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [57.9 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata [295 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,844 kB in 2s (759 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
32 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

# 
# 
# apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.2/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
libapache2-mod-php7.3/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
libargon2-0/bionic 0~20190702-0.1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 0~20161029-1.1]
php-cli/bionic 2:8.0+84+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [upgradable from: 2:7.4+75+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php-dev/bionic 2:8.0+84+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [upgradable from: 2:7.4+75+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php-igbinary/bionic 3.2.4+2.0.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 3.1.2+2.0.8-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php-memcached/bionic 3.1.5+2.2.0-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 3.1.4+2.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+20191129]
php-msgpack/bionic 2.1.2+0.5.7-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 2.1.0+0.5.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php-xml/bionic 2:8.0+84+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [upgradable from: 2:7.4+75+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.2-cli/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-common/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-curl/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-gd/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-json/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-mbstring/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-mysql/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-opcache/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-readline/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-snmp/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-xml/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.2-zip/bionic 7.2.34-23+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.8]
php7.3-cli/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-common/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-gd/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-json/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-mbstring/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-mysql/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-opcache/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-readline/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-snmp/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-xml/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.3-zip/bionic 7.3.29-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 i386 [upgradable from: 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1]
#
```

Comment: Do you really need a 32-bit OS or was just convenient to upgrade? If not then please install 64-bit. The 32-bit architecture is as good as dead.

Comment: Remove the `-f` from your apt commands unless you *really* mean it and are prepared for the consequences. Go down the rabbit-hole shown in your output: Try to install `mariadb-server-10.2`. If it fails, the output will tell you why. If you don't understand the output, add it to your question above.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - convenient upgrade to run librenms. This install started with ubuntu 12.

Comment: @user535733  when trying to install mariadb-server-10.2.

Comment: Your output seems clear: `Package mariadb-server-10.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: @user535733, Thanks, any idea how to fix it ?. or make xenial packages run on bionic ?.

Comment: Please add to your Question above the complete output of `sudo apt update`. You have not finished troubleshooting the problem yet, so a solution is premature. You cannot make 16.04 packages run on 18.04 without doing horrible things to your system.